# flutter: check if the document exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check whether the document exist or not without creating the document if it does not exits

```
Checked() {   
Future<DocumentSnapshot> check =  linkref.
   document(user.UID).
   collection("Requests").
   document(uuid).get();
   return FutureBuilder(
       future: check,
       builder: (context, ccheck) {
         if (check != null ) {
           return Text("Available");
         }
         return Text("not available);



       });
 }
```

i tried this code but even if the document does not exists it says that it exists

Answer (score 1):

You should use; `if (ccheck.data.exists)` instead of `if (check != null )`. Here is the code;

```
Checked() {
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> check =
      linkref.document(user.UID).collection("Requests").document(uuid).get();
  return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: check,
      builder: (context, ccheck) {
        if (ccheck.data.exists) {
          return Text("Available");
        }
        return Text("not available");
      });
}
```

Comment: You're most welcome. To help next visitors, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **.where( field, isEqualTo: query)**. This might be useful to you.

```
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

checkExists(String query) async {
  QuerySnapshot checker = await userRef
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: query)
      .get();

  chkr.docs.forEach((doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      print('Exists');
      print(doc.get('uid'));
    }else {
      print('false');
    }
  });
}
```

Then, if you are using a button, you can use **onPressed: () => check(yourQuery)**.